# Touching up Tough as Tile Paint

Tags: bathtub

I refinished our bathtub with tough as tile paint and it looked great until we retiled around the tub and scratched the paint in multiple places. Is it ok to give the tub another coat over top of where its scratched without sanding?? I redid sinks before and had a run in the one; tried sanding it and repainting and it reacted and we ended up replacing it. I DO NOT want to replace our tub...

Comment: not meant to be snide remarks: what does the label say? Have you tried the paint manufacturers website or FAQs?

Comment: It only gives directions on applying when you apply the first coat and does not give you any info on touching up the product after its been applied. Thank you for the suggestion, i will check their website!

Comment: In the future I would follow the process of : fix tiles, do painting then seal tiles ie grout as necessary. That way you reduce the risk of scratches from handling tiles...

Answer (score 1):

There's a link to the applcation instructions on their website.
https://www.homaxproducts.com/kitchen-bath/sink-tile-refinishing/tough-as-tile-one-part-finish-spray-on-kit-white (this page is not the instructions but contains a non-transferrable link )

It says not to allow it to cure for more than 6 hourse before recoating, so you'll have to re-do the surface preparation around your repairs or on the whole tub and then re-coat.

I see no indications that it is not self-compatible - that is it can be applied over an existing tough-as-tiles finish if the preparation instructions are followed (again)

Comment: I’ve not had good luck with those paints lasting but it sounds like this did and redoing it may be a good idea to hide the scratches.

Answer (score 1):

### Do not violate the recoat window

Paints dry (lose wetness and stop being sticky).  Put salt water in a tray, and it'll dry leaving a coat of salt; thats's drying.   As a totally separate action, they also cure (polymerize into long tough molecules); this polymerization is what makes paint not whitewash, and what allows cured paint to resist its own solvent.  Mix 2 parts of epoxy for a very obvious example of *curing*.   **Drying and curing happen on separate timetables**.

Most paints will give you a "recoat window" indicating when you can apply a second coat.  Typically there are 2 recoat window periods:

- Your first blackout period is when the paint is still wet. If you second-coat it now, it'll turn into a gooey mess. When that ends...
- Your first recoat window is when the paint hasn't **cured** too much, and it's still possible for the second coat to get a *chemical bond* with the first coat - i.e. the two coats can co-polymerize.
- Your second blackout period is when the paint is too cured for a chemical bond to be possible, but still not cured *fully*, meaning that if you try to scuff-sand to create a dull surface with microscopic jagged peaks, the peaks will collapse.  **This period can be months**.
- Your second recoat window is after the cure is totally complete.  Now it is possible to **scuff-sand** the old surface to create microscopic jagged mountains, that will give a new coat (of any coating) something to grab on to.  This mechanical bond is inferior to a chemical bond, but what can you do?

You will need to consult the label or the factory for when those recoat windows are.  **If you violate a recoat window, your paint will fail catastrophically**.  You will either need to replace your tub, or find a sufficiently robust paint stripper that you can remove it all, strip it to enamel, and reapply on the original enamel.  *Won't that be fun!*

### Do not fail to scuff-sand

Everyone who has ever painted, including me, strongly desires to avoid this tedious and laborious chore.  **And if you do, your paint will fail catastrophically**.

Tub coatings are a very difficult application.  You are asking a lot out of it.  You're asking *even more than you realize*, because it is stratospherically difficult to manufacture paint that tough without resorting to 2-part epoxies and LPUs. Which they must avoid because the B-part is an immune system irritant that can do crippling damage to someone who tries to spray it without a moon suit.  (it's offered in garage floor paint *only* because who sprays their garage floor?)

So, you must not only scuff-sand but you must do so fastidiously without missing a spot, because this coating is under such significant stress due to hot/cold and people walking on it. Any weak spot will fail quickly.

Mind you, there's no need to sand to any depth; in fact blowing through to the enamel is counterproductive.  The purpose is to microscopically roughen the surface so it looks like jagged mountains all the way across, not like a flat plateau with a canyon here and there.  The better you do this job, the better the job holds.

Comment: I sprayed a roof with 2 part,  I had a 3 foot extension on the spray gun and I guess there was enough breeze that noting bad happened to me.  also put a 2 part polyurethane on a solid hardwood floor, I used a kind of mop for that.  it might have been a different kind of two-part.